# Gradle Sync failed:Could not find method compile() for arguments

Tags: android

i am refering this   https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started to integrate mopub in my app. I got an error "could not find method compile for arguments" while adding mopub-sdk dependency in my project's build.gradle file.Please help me out.
Build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {

    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }}
    allprojects {


    repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {

    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.14.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // For banners
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-banner:4.14.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // For interstitials
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-interstitial:4.14.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // For rewarded videos. This will automatically also include 
      interstitials
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-rewardedvideo:4.14.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // For native static (images).
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-static:4.14.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // For native video. This will automatically also include native static
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-native-video:4.14.0@aar') 
    {transitive = true}
    }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

Actual Error:-

```
Error:(31, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.14.0@aar, build_7edkg2m28hxg79jomt8w3j8ic$_run_closure1$_closure4$_closure5@1c36532] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your dependencies in the *other* `build.gradle`. They belong to the individual module `build.gradle` files.

Also, you are importing `com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.14.0@aar`, which contains **all** of the ad format dependencies you already have below in your Gradle file. You only need `com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.14.0@aar` **or** the modularized artifacts.